# Explanation needed for problem related with differential equation $w''(x)-q^2 w(x)=0.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am stuck on the following problem:

> Suppose that $q \in \Bbb C.$ Consider the differential equation $w''(x)-q^2 w(x)=0.$ If every solution of this equation satisfies $$\sup_{T >0} \frac{1}{2T} \int_{-T}^{T}|w(t)|dt < \infty$$, then prove that $\text{Re}(q)=0.$

My Attempt:The solution of  the D.E. is given by $w(x)=Ae^{qx}+Be^{-qx},$ where $A,B$ being constants. Now,we compute $\displaystyle \int_{-T}^{T}|w(t)|dt=....=\frac{1}{q}(e^{qT}-e^{-qT})(A-B)$ so that $ \displaystyle \frac{1}{2T} \int_{-T}^{T}|w(t)|dt=\frac{A-B}{qT} \sinh {qT}.$

Now I am not sure how to progress from here. Any idea about how to go with the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, the general solution is given by $$w=Ae^{qx}+Be^{-qx} \tag1$$ Let's consider what this means: you can pick any real numbers $A$ and $B$ that you want, and (1)  will give you a solution. By assumption, that solution will satisfy
$$
\sup_{T>0} \frac{1}{2T}\int_{-T}^T |w(x)|\,dx <\infty \tag2
$$

That's a lot of freedom you have, picking $A$ and $B$. Use it wisely, making the choices that turn (2) into something tractable.

Here is one such choice: $A=1$, $B=0$. (I set $B$ to zero because I have no desire  to integrate the absolute value of a sum.) With my choice, (2) turns into
$$
\sup_{T>0} \frac{1}{2T}\int_{-T}^T |e^{qx}|\,dx <\infty  \tag3
$$
Now is the time to recall that $|e^{qx}|=e^{(\mathrm{Re}\,q)x}$. Plug this into (3), integrate (noting that antiderivative looks different when $\mathrm{Re}\,q=0$ and when $\mathrm{Re}\,q\ne 0$), and draw your conclusion.